# Name/Type of this Graph

Tags: graph

I would like to know the name or type of this graph:

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is a TypeScript question; should you remove that tag?

Comment: I mean, I'm gonna have to code the graph in Typescript right?

Answer (score 0):

You can model this easily using a gantt chart. You would have time at the bottom and each provider on the horizontal axis with color coding for their status.

## Example

[image]

## More

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart